# How to add a random number in slug that already exists in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql, slug

Currently a document looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "630f3c32c1a580642a9ff4a0"
  },
  "title": "This is a title",
  "slug": "this-is-a-title",
  "Post": "this is a post"
}
```

But I want it like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "630f3c32c1a580642a9ff4a0"
  },
  "title": "This is a title",
  "slug": "this-is-a-title-548631",
  "Post": "this is a post"
}
```

How can I add a 6 digit random number at the end of slug in all documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$rand](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/rand/) to generate a random number, combined with some other operators you can force the 6 digits constraint, like so:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      slug: {
        $concat: [
          "$slug",
          "-",
          {
            $toString: {
              $round: {
                $add: [
                  {
                    $multiply: [
                      {
                        $rand: {}
                      },
                      899999
                    ]
                  },
                  100000
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w4fxZ645qtN)

(this will gives results in the range of 100,000 to 999,999), if you want to allow 0 prefixes, like `000123` then you can still use the same approach and pad with zeros based on the number length.